# AWS IOT Core - Search Index rest api call failed with resource not found error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, iot, aws-iot

I am trying to access AWS IOT searchIndex feature as per below post.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_SearchIndex.html

I am using URL as below.

https://a1bseglysxoew2-ats.iot.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/indices/search with aws V4 authentication. But every time I am getting resource not found Error.

{"message":"Not Found","traceId":"bb84265c-07f3-66de-415e-9351d70870ec"}

I have quertion regarding base url. Which base url I have to user to make rest api call ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this endpoint: `https://iot.<REGION>.amazonaws.com` for AWS IoT Search and other control plane APIs.

The `*-ats` endpoint is a [data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot-data/index.html) plane endpoint which is used by Things to perform connections, publishes, subscribes and the like.